# What Order are the '5-days' Games Meant to be Played In?

Tags: fully-ramblomatic

The *5 Days* games from [Fully Ramblomatic](http://www.fullyramblomatic.com/games.htm) are titled pretty ambiguously.  I want to play them in the correct order of plot timelines, or if that doesn't apply, in the order they were released.

Do the games' plots tie in to one another?  If yes, what chronological order are the games in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The games were released out of chronological order and are intended to be played order of release:

- 5 Days A Stranger
- 7 Days A Skeptic
- Trilby's Notes
- 6 Days A Sacrifice

7 Days and Notes do not strongly tie into each other, but each game tends to assume you've played through previous games.

Chronologically, the events of each game occur in the following years, derived from the descriptions of 6 Days and Notes:

- 1993 — 5 Days A Stranger
- 1997 — Trilby's Notes
- 2189 — 6 Days A Sacrifice
- 2385 — 7 Days A Skeptic